# Selenium webdriver -keep clicking on next button of calendar until the month title match found using java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, calendar

I want to keep click on the next button until the particular month is found on the calendar.All the locators perfectly working I think the problem is with the loop anyone plz help me with this.

The link for the website(HTML):[https://www.redbus.in/]

```
    WebDriver driver; 
    @BeforeClass    
    public void openbrowser()   
    {       
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "./drivers/geckodriver");      
    driver=new FirefoxDriver();         
    driver.get("https://www.redbus.in/");       
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40l, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
    } 
    @Test   
    public void onwardDate()    
    { 
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='fl search-box date-box gtm-onwardCalendar']")).click();    
    System.out.println("date box got clicked");     
    String month="Apr 2018";        
    String date="28";       
    String getMonth=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='rb-calendar']//td[@class='monthTitle']")).getText();         
    System.out.println(getMonth);   
    try     
    {       
      while(true)   
      {             
      if(!(getMonth.equalsIgnoreCase(month))) 
            {
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='rb-
                calendar']/*//td[@class='next']")).click();
                break;      
            }       
      }         
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='rb-calendar_onward_cal']/table/tbody//td[text()='"+month+"']/../..//td[text()='"+date+"']")).click();         
      System.out.println("date got picked");
       }

catch(Exception e)      
 {      

 } }}
```

Comment: Please describe your problem. What isn't working?

Comment: @ventiseis It is not clicking the next button in loop.I want to click the next button until the month match is found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. Specify the question good. I have to guess what is problem here.**

**2. I try to run your code in IntelliJ IDEA and code does not compile.**

**3. You really need to read Java style conventions and know clear code java rules if you want to share your code with other people.**

**4. This is solution in your idea, but you need consider all code. In each rotation of loop you need to get value of variable.**

Solution:

```
while(true) {
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"rb-calendar_onward_cal\"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/button")).click();
            String lol = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='rb-calendar_onward_cal']/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]")).getText();
            if (lol.equals(month)) break;
        }
```